# Powershell script to expand multi-valued cells into rows

Tags: powershell

I have a csv file with cells containing multi-valued data. I am trying to split multi-values in to rows running down the columns. I put examples below of input and desired output.

This is the csv file

Name Group  Owner         Delegate

Mike Group1 Mike,Ash,Matt A,B,C
Mike Group2 Mike          D,E
Mike Group3 Ash           F
Mike Group4 Matt          F
Mike Group5 Matt,Ash      A,C
Mike Group6 Ash,Mike      B,D
Mike Group7 Mike          F

This is how I would like the data after processing:

Name Group  Owner Delegate

Mike Group1 Mike  A
Mike Group1 Mike  B
Mike Group1 Mike  C
Mike Group1 Ash   A
Mike Group1 Ash   B
Mike Group1 Ash   C
Mike Group1 Matt  A
Mike Group1 Matt  B
Mike Group1 Matt  C
Mike Group2 Mike  D
Mike Group2 Mike  E
Mike Group3 Ash   F
Mike Group4 Matt  F
Mike Group5 Matt  A
Mike Group5 Matt  C
Mike Group5 Ash   A
Mike Group5 Ash   C
Mike Group6 Ash   B
Mike Group6 Ash   D
Mike Group6 Mike  B
Mike Group6 Mike  D
Mike Group7 Mike  F

Comment: What the contents of the CSV file `EmailData2.csv` look like?

Comment: It looks like the top picture, I hope you can see it, and I'm trying to get it to look like the bottom picture. So column A (DLGroup) does not need to be split, just aligned to the "owner" , "member" data. I'd load up the input file but just couldn't see how to do it. When I run the script column A comes up blank. Appreciate your help.

Comment: No, it doesn't. It shows how a spreadsheet application represents the contents of the file. But what's actually the file text? Is the delimiter comma? Are text values inside quotation marks, etc.?

Comment: Hi, it's a comma delimited csv file and the delimiter in the cell values is a semi-colon ; Text values are not inside quotation marks when I open it as txt file. Thanks

Comment: I have added text above so you can build the csv file. Hope this helps ?

Comment: I can't see a clear pattern of what it is you're even after. It looks like you're enumerating the cross product of owners and members but your example is missing `1000@test.com.au` and `1018@test.com.au`. Also, the logic used for numbering of the groups is completely unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$getcsv= Import-csv D:\Mike\Temp5.csv
$table=@()
foreach ($user in $getcsv) {
    foreach($own in $user.Owner -split','){
        foreach($del in $user.Delegate -split','){
$table+=[pscustomobject]@{
Name = $user.Name
Group = $user.Group
Owner = $own
Delegate = $del
}
}}}
$table
```